# Firebase Auth using phone number returns an internal error

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-authentication

I set up my app to be able to send Apple Notifications using firebase and I verified that it works using the console. Now I want to do phone authentication which is built on top of APN.

So I wrote this:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) { verificationID, error in
  if error != nil {
    print("Verification code not sent \(error!)")
  } else {
    print ("Successful.")
  }
```

And I get:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170046db0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 500;
    message = "<null>";
}}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.}
```

Any idea? Should I file a bug against firebase?

I am using iOS SDK 4.0.0 (latest zip I could find.)

**UPDATE:**

I disabled method swizzling by adding `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `info.plist` and set it to `NO`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Pass device token to auth.
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
}
```

Comment: can you please post the code wherein you set setAPNSToken in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method ?

Comment: Updated. Thank you.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tested with latest **Firebase iOS SDK i.e. 4.0.0** and **Xcode 8.3**

Firstly , remove this key `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` from info.plist. This is not needed.

Now in **AppDelegate.swift** add following functions

```
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Pass device token to auth.
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()

    //At development time we use .sandbox
    firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)

    //At time of production it will be set to .prod
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()

    if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
        print(userInfo)
        return
    }
}*
```

**Send a verification code to the user's phone:**

In the class where you want to integrate Phone Authentication write :

**Note** : I have added `+91` as its country code for India. You can add country code according to your region.

```
 PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber("+919876543210") { (verificationID, error) in
       if ((error) != nil) {
             // Verification code not sent.
             print(error)
       } else {
              // Successful. User gets verification code 
              // Save verificationID in UserDefaults
             UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "firebase_verification")
             UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
             //And show the Screen to enter the Code.
       }
```

**Sign in the user with the verification code**:

```
 let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firebase_verification")
 let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID! as! String, verificationCode: self.txtEmailID.text!)

   Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: {(_ user: User, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
         if error != nil {
            // Error
          }else {
             print("Phone number: \(user.phoneNumber)")
              var userInfo: Any? = user.providerData[0]
                    print(userInfo)
                }
         } as! AuthResultCallback)
```

Comment: Do you think there is any limit to the number of text verification messages sent ?

Comment: I have tried sending code to my number 30 times a day during testing. @JenJose

Comment: Still I am facing "Invalid token." issue.

Comment: I solved this with updated valid push notification certificate

Comment: yes the issue resolved by uploading new p12 files to firebase.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was the apns token type that was wrong:

```
Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)
```

should have been:

```
Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
```

Comment: You can also specify type: .unknown for Firebase to detect it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Double check that the app bundle ID in Xcode matches the bundle ID in Firebase **exactly**. And by **exactly**, make sure their case matches - Xcode likes to use mixed case by default for the app name part of the bundle ID.

If you end up changing the bundle ID in Xcode, make sure to manually delete the provisioning profile for the app before generating a new one in Xcode, or it will repeatedly fail (Apple apparently ignores case on profile names).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case I have sending wrong `self.verificationID` to `FIRAuthCredential`.
If you are having this error, then please print your `verificationID` and check, is that the same one you are sending to `FIRAuthCredential`.

Here is my code in `objC` :

```
[[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider] verifyPhoneNumber:self.phoneNumberTextField.text
                                            UIDelegate:nil
                                            completion:^(NSString * _Nullable verificationID, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"error %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                                NSLog(@"verificationID %@", verificationID);
                                                self.verificationID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", verificationID];

//                                                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//                                                [defaults setObject:verificationID forKey:@"authVerificationID"];
//                                                NSString *verificationID = [defaults stringForKey:@"authVerificationID"];

                                                // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
                                                // ...
                                            }];
```

I accidentally send wrong verificationID here :

`self.verificationID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"verificationID",];`

Right one is this :

`self.verificationID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", verificationID];`

And then I send it to `FIRAuthCredential` like this :

```
FIRAuthCredential *credential = [[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider]
                                     credentialWithVerificationID:self.verificationID
                                     verificationCode:self.pinCodeTextField.text];

    [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential
                              completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                  if (error) {
                                      NSLog(@"error %@", error);
                                      return;
                                  }
                                  NSLog(@"Success");
                                  // User successfully signed in. Get user data from the FIRUser object
                                  // ...
                              }];
```

Which return `success` successfully. Hope it will help to others.

Answer (score 0):

i am solve it easy make type .sandbox

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Pass device token to auth.
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    //At development time we use .sandbox
    firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
}
```

and remove this line from code

```
Auth.auth().settings.isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting = TRUE
```