# "Invalid Token" when trying to authenticate phone number using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

This is my code:

```
import FirebaseAuth


class AuthPhoneNum {

    static func getPhoneNum(phoneNumber: String) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) { (verificationID, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
        }
    }

    static func verify(verificationCode: String?) {
        guard let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID") else { return }
        if verificationCode != nil {
            let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
                withVerificationID: verificationID,
                verificationCode: verificationCode!)

            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("No verification code")
        }
    }

}
```

This is what the console prints out:

> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17048 "Invalid token."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid token.,
>   error_name=INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL}

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You should provide a proper code example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i updated my post.

Comment: I have answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091666/firebase-auth-using-phone-number-returns-an-internal-error/44241143#44241143

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Auth using phone number returns an internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091666/firebase-auth-using-phone-number-returns-an-internal-error)

Comment: 'Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and won't work on a simulator.' If that's not the issue, did you enable phone number authentication in your console?

Comment: For me it was that I had not correctly uploaded the APN key to Firebase

Comment: How did you fix it @JordanTate ?

Comment: I have had the same error. My case was related to App Store Account as my developer account is under review of upgrading from Individual to Company account.

Answer (score 35):

I was also experiencing this problem. Checked the following:

- Correct bundle Id
- Correct Google-Info.plist
- Correct `aps-environment` value
- Correct APNS token type when calling `auth.setAPNStoken` (`.unknown` for auto detect)

Nothing helped until in Firebase app settings I **uploaded the APNS authentication key (p8) instead of certificates** - I used those certificates before for push notifications only and everything was working fine but for phone number notifications something went wrong.

Comment: I was also missing the APNs .p12 file in Firebase console. Once I Uploaded the .p12 then it worked.

Comment: Do you mean .p8 @AnilGupta, because i couldn't find adding .p12 APN anywhere

Comment: @algrid Where `aps-environment` ?

Comment: hiii i need help

Comment: Where do you upload the p12?!

Comment: When I deleted my APNS key and re-uploaded it it worked. 

Comment: I am using FlutterFire, I was seeing this problem, and re-uploading the APNS key solved the problem. Thank you @maxhawkins!!!

Answer (score 30):

It is most likely that you need to upload an .p8 Key file
(I have an Enterprise account but same thing for developer)
In Apple Developer Account:

- All Keys
- Create New Key (+)
  [image]
- Type in Global name for all of your apps
- Checkbox next to Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)
  [image]
- Download your p8 file
- Upload to firebase dashboard
  [image]

Comment: It worked for me. No need to build. It can be worked in all the release build also.

Comment: very well explained. Just a repeat, make sure to add following in appdelegate
<code>
   override init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
</code>

Answer (score 8):

First regenerates APNS key and upload in firebase for cloud messaging

1) Import Firebase and FirebaseAuth

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
```

2) In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Configure firebase.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

3) Write these two func in AppDelegate.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
        print(userInfo)
        return
    }
}
```

Very Important note : `uthAPNSTokenType` set correctly for [sandbox / production] or set for common `.unknown`

In my case it was the apns token type that was wrong:

```
Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)
```

should have been:

```
Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
```

Comment: I was not allowed to replace APNS Certificate.But changing to sandbox worked for me.Thank you so much

Comment: i am face same issue in react native ios release build...after adding prod code in appdelegate.m its worked. thanks buddy

Comment: i really tried a lot, but the sandbox type worked, finally! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

same problem questions have been before on SO. so would like to tell you setup all pre-require step before run code.

**Pre-Require Steps:**

- Register bundle id on Developer account and enable notifications for
  bundle id.
- Register same bundle id on firebase console setting page and create
  app, download Google-Info.plist file, make sure name should be same.
- Upload Push certificates on firebase console for sandbox as well as
  development.
- follow this below link for code implementation.

[setup code for Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913105/token-mismatch-using-phone-number-authentication-ios/53914196#53914196)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was an **incorrect bundle id in the iOS app, in the firebase project settings** (Project settings -> General -> Your apps).

I hope this helps anyone overlooking the same detail.

Comment: This was my issue. I delete the /ios folder for some reason and after that I forgot to set the correct bundle id

Answer (score 3):

For any one else who double checked the above and still have issues, don't forget to add your team ID and App Id in your ios config file.

And, don't forget to download it again, and replace your old one with the updated one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In my case, it was an incorrect `Team ID`. Perhaps `App Store ID` is not necessarily - I have it blank and it works anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that it is APNs that you are selected under Key Services. The number of APNs certificates per developer account is limited to 2. So if you already had 2 certificates before, there is a chance that you are created the certificate by checking DeviceCheck instead of APNs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem when I want send OTP and get notifications, I created APN key on apple developer console then added it to firebase after that everything got well:[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried adding the APNs key (p8) in your Firebase console and also checked for the Correct bundle Id and Correct Google-Info.plist.
And still the issue persists
Do check if you have "Push Notifications" enabled and "Remote notifications" selected in "Signing and capabilities" in Xcode->Runner but are not actually using firebase messaging
Then care to uncheck "Remote notifications"  from "Signing and capabilities" and remove  "Push Notifications" in Xcode->Runner.
In my case this was the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything right as per the documentation. Try one thing.

Paste this line in AppDelegate.m under,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

 [[FIRAuth auth] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRAuthAPNSTokenTypeProd];
```