# Firebase phone auth Error: Invalid token. at nativeToJSError

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using `firebase` phone auth in react native app with this [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/), I tested it in some different devices. sometimes the phone `auth` works and sometimes it throws this error

> firebase phone auth Error: Invalid token. at nativeToJSError

[image]

I have gone through the docs of firebase and try to understand this error.
Here is my code snippet:

```js
confirmPhone = async(phoneNumber) => {
  const phoneWithAreaCode = phoneNumber.replace(/^0+/, '+972');
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    firebase.auth().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneWithAreaCode)
      .on('state_changed', async(phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
        switch (phoneAuthSnapshot.state) {
          case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFIED:
            UserStore.setVerificationId(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId)
            await this.confirmCode(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId, phoneAuthSnapshot.code, phoneAuthSnapshot)
            res(phoneAuthSnapshot)

            break

          case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.CODE_SENT:
            UserStore.setVerificationId(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId)
            res(phoneAuthSnapshot)
            break

          case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFY_TIMEOUT:
            UserStore.setVerificationId(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId)
            UserStore.setErrorCodeAuthentication('SMS code has expired')
            res(phoneAuthSnapshot)


          case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.ERROR:
            console.log(phoneAuthSnapshot.error.code)
            if (phoneAuthSnapshot.error) {
              this.showMessageErrorByCode(phoneAuthSnapshot.error.code)

            }

            rej(phoneAuthSnapshot)
            break

        }
      })
  })
}

confirmCode = async(verificationId, code, phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
  console.log(verificationId, code);
  try {
    const credential = await firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code)
    UserStore.setCodeInput(code)
    UserStore.setUserCredentials(credential)
    AppStore.setAlreadyVerifiedAuto(true)
    await this.authenticate(credential)
    return credential
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    this.showMessageErrorByCode(e.error.code)


    //    throw new Error(e)
  }
}

showMessageErrorByCode(errorcode) {
  switch (errorcode) {
    case 'auth/invalid-phone-number':
      UserStore.setErrorCodeAuthentication('Please enter valid phone number');
      break;
    case 'auth/unknown':
      {
        UserStore.setErrorCodeAuthentication('User blocked by firebase');
        break;
      }

    case 'auth/session-expired':
      {
        UserStore.setErrorCodeAuthentication('SMS code has expired');
        break;
      }
    case 'auth/invalid-verification-code':
      {
        UserStore.setErrorCodeAuthentication('Code verification not correct');
        break;
      }
    default:
      UserStore.setErrorCodeAuthentication('other error');

  }
}

authenticate = async(credential) => {
  await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)

}

//...
```

Comment: Have you had a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091583/invalid-token-when-trying-to-authenticate-phone-number-using-firebase

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Seeing the exact same error.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54800057/4295614

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid Token" when trying to authenticate phone number using firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091583/invalid-token-when-trying-to-authenticate-phone-number-using-firebase)

Answer (score 2):

Check the following:

- Correct bundle Id
- Correct Google-Info.plist
- Correct aps-environment value
- Upload the APNS authentication key (p8) instead of certificates

Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can happen if the bundle id of the app trying to access firebase doesn't match the bundle id registered in the firebase console.