# Firebase Phone Authentication Error: Invalid Token (Even after replacing APNs Key)

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Today may production app started having issues on Phone Authentication through Firebase on several devices (but not all).

When I make the call `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: uiDelegate:)` I get the following error:

`Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17048 "Invalid token." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid token., error_name=INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL`

As per [Firebase documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/6566328dc461c38c6000c64996c17883b9895d06/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuthErrors.h#L246), this code indicates that an invalid APNS device token was used in the verifyClient request.

Nothing in my app code has changed, yet this error is occurring. I uploaded a new APNs Key and .p8 file as other StackOverflow posts have suggested, with no luck.

I have tried the suggestions in [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091583/invalid-token-when-trying-to-authenticate-phone-number-using-firebase).

I am also able to receive push notifications from my app to this device, so it isn't like my push notifications aren't working.

Could anyone suggest ways of debugging his?

Edit: This is the method I am calling:

```
func sendVerificationCode(to phoneNumber: String, _ completion: @escaping (Error?)->Void) {
  PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
     /* store verificationID locally if exists */
     completion(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Having a very similar situation tonight also. Please update the question if you figure anything out! Thanks.

Comment: @bmovement Hmm interesting. I've been keeping my eye on https://status.firebase.google.com and Auth doesn't have any marked outages but I wonder if its a problem on their end. Will update if I hear anything else.

Comment: Also experiencing this.. error_name: INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL nserror-code: 17048  nserror-domain: FIRAuthErrorDomain, NSLocalizedDescription: 
Invalid token.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rromanchuk/12539c4d742c6f61b58f1bc07f1528ea

Comment: @JakeG Looks like Firebase fixed it this morning, but I'm sure you know that :)

Comment: @bmovement I am still getting the error. Yours just started working without doing anything else?

Comment: @bmovement So strange - I got a "Token Mismatch" error (instead of Invalid Token), then I started getting Invalid Token again, and now it seems to be fixed.

Comment: @JakeG Gross... fingers crossed that it stays fixed.

Comment: checkout this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54800057/4295614

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There was an issue where iOS clients were not receiving the text messages required for one-time password authentication. Its status is being tracked here: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/18006

From there:

> We are investigating an issue with Firebase Phone authentication that affects iOS devices. Affected customers may see "invalid token" error during OTP verification.

This issue has been fixed, since 11:15 am pacific time. If you're still seeing similar problems, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Has issue fixed yet?