# Invalid token when logging in using a phone number

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-ios

I have a mobile application (React Native) to which I can log in using a phone number

In the Android version everything works fine

The problem is with iOS:

```
  onSignIn() {
    const { code, phoneNumber } = this.state;
    const newNumber = '+' + code + phoneNumber;
    if (newNumber.length > 10) {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(newNumber)
        .then(confirmResult => {
          this.setState({ result: confirmResult });
          const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: 'SecurityCode',
            params: { phoneAuthResponse: confirmResult },
          });
          this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.message === 'TOO SHORT') {
            alert('Please enter a valid phone number');
          } else {
            alert(error.message);
          }
        });
    } else {
      alert('Please Enter Your Number');
    }
  }
```

A modal opens with information like on the screen

[image]

Is somewhere written step by step what should be met? Tests on TestFlight

Comment: I looked at similar questions on various pages and after testing everything still does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091583/invalid-token-when-trying-to-authenticate-phone-number-using-firebase